# ArrayList.IndexOf returns -1 in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Please i am confused. I have an Arraylist with a size of 184 . Among my list is 25

[1] = 25

[2] = 30 etc.

I am trying to return index of an item example. returns 0 where item is 25 returns 1 where 30. However, what ever item i used . When i used

```
int l = myArray.IndexOf(myItem) ;
```

It returns -1. My item is 30. I then replace myitem with 30

```
int l = myArray.IndexOf(30) ;
int l = myArray.IndexOf("30") ;
```

Both returns -1. however, when i tried

```
int l = Convert.ToInt16( myArray[2]);
```

The above returns 30. Please where did i go wrong ? this is the first time i encounter this. I am confused. I inturn tried.

```
int l = myArray.IndexOf("30", 1) ;
int l = myArray.IndexOf(30 ,1) ;
```

Yet nothing helps .

**Update**

Thank you all for your time.

I had to use list as suggested by the user below. Thank you once again man. If you  write ur answer , i will accept it perhaps it may help some one . I modify my code like below. It works now , but i am not sure why the ListArray fails.

```
   List<long> li = new List<long>();
      foreach (long item in arlClientID)
          li.Add(item);

      int h = li.IndexOf(searchDuplicate.clientid);
```

Comment: I suggest you don't use ArrayList. Use `List<int>` instead.

Comment: What is `myItem` an `int`?

Comment: How are you adding items to the list?

Comment: You'll need to post a better code example, one that shows the declaration of `myArray` and `myItem` and exactly how you initialize those variables and add elements to `myArray`. In the meantime, if you take Blorgbeard's advice, that very likely would fix your problem simply by preventing you from misusing the object (one of the great benefits of generic types).

Comment: @ Blorgbeard it works when i use the List u suggested. Though not sure why .

Answer (score 2):

The reason @Blorgbeard suggested you to use List instead of [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) is because Arraylist is non-generic collection and thus when you add an item to arraylist it accepts object rather than int\string etc. More Info [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

The reason I suspect you are getting -1 as output is probably 30 is not an integer in "myArray" but a string as described below:-

```
            ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
            myArray.Add(25);
            myArray.Add(50);
            myArray.Add("30");
            Console.WriteLine(myArray.IndexOf(30)); // Returns  -1
            Console.WriteLine(myArray.IndexOf("30")); // Returns  2
```

So, its much better and safe to use generic List collection rather than ArrayList.

Comment: THanks for the explanationn Rahul. What confused me more was , i tried the int and string logic. I tried "30" & 30 all to no avail.

Comment: I notice that you are using `long` now. If you were adding `long`s to your ArrayList, that would explain it. You can't compare a boxed long to an `int`. Try this: `myArray.Add(30L); Console.WriteLine(myArray.IndexOf(30));` -- because the ArrayList contains a `long` (`30L`), it won't find an `int` with the same value (`30`).